# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError al compilar "compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime"

Tags: java

Al compilar por cmd me aparece esto

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: HolaMundo has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 56.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

¿Cuál es el error?

Comment: A simple vista creo que existe problemas de compatibilidad entre versiones, te sugiero reinstalar la ultima version de Java por si acaso

Comment: Bienvenido Osbaldo, te recomiendo que visites: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para que veas cómo realizar preguntas de buena calidad y https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla.

Answer (score 1):

Las versiones de la JRE:

```
Java SE 13 = 57 (0x39 hex)
Java SE 12 = 56 (0x38 hex)
Java SE 11 = 55 (0x37 hex)
Java SE 10 = 54 (0x36 hex)
Java SE 9 = 53 (0x35 hex)
Java SE 8 = 52 (0x34 hex)
```

Por algún motivo parece que has compilado usando Java 12, pero intentas ejecutarlo con la JRE de Java 8.

Comprueba con `javac -version` y `java -version` si estás usando las versiones correctas.

Answer (score 0):

Leyendo el error:

> "HolaMundo has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 56.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0",

Interpretado al buen español:

El proyecto fue compilado usando una nueva versión del Java Runtime Engine (JRE), la versión que tienes está desactualizada.

La solución:

Actualizar tu JRE a la nueva versión.

Comment: gracias.
pero tengo actualizado todo ya que apenas acabo de iniciar en esto y todas las actualizaciones ya estan instaladas  JRE y JDK

Comment: versión mas reciente de JRE 8update221   16 julio 2019

Comment: ¿Qué sucedió para que aceptaras la respuesta? ¿Hubo versiones diferentes?

Comment: soy nuevo en esto y no se muy bien como funciona

Comment: por eso, revisa el tour :) el enlace está en el comentario que dejé en tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Mi solucion fue abrir el monitor de tomcat, click derecho en el icono de monitor tomcat del menu del reloj, configure (o configuración creo que es en español) y en la pestaña de titulo Java en el box de Java Virtual Machine cambie el jre 1.8.0  a la version de java que uso actualmente que es la 16 (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16\bin\server\jvm.dll).

El error ocurre porque la configuracion de Tomcat para el servidor y el del entorno de trabajo son de diferentes versiones asi que seguramente tomcat o el servidor que tengas tenga una version mas antigua que no soporta la mas nueva con la que compilas en eclipse (o el ide que uses)